# SQL query help needed joining and counting within a table

Tags: sql, select, sum

This is my second post related to my join. Now I want to have a table that has the sum of counts for the males and females...

I have a table called babynames that looks abit like this:

```
firstname |sex |year |count 
Bob |M| 2010| 150
Bob |M| 2009| 100
Bob |M| 2008| 122
Bob |F| 2007| 2
Bob |F| 2001| 1
```

I've been able to count all the baby names that are both male and female with this query

```
SELECT 
  firstname, sum(count), sex
FROM babynames
GROUP BY firstname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sex) = 2
```

resulting table:

```
bob|375|M
```

That is close to what I want....but

```
SELECT 
  firstname, sum(count), sex
FROM babynames GROUP BY firstname, sex
```

gives me the results:

```
bob|372|M
bob|3|F
```

Now, i need to get the best of both worlds so that my table ONLY has names where the sex matches and ideally looks like this:

```
firstname|male count| female count
bob |372|3
```

While I admit I need some practice with SQL, I'd appreciate some help pulling this query together. Thanks!!

Comment: thanks for the formatting JW - I'll make sure in the future to better format my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  firstname,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'm' THEN count END) MaleCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'f' THEN count END) FemaleCount
FROM    babynames 
GROUP   BY firstname
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e619f/2)

Comment: well done!! i just need now to filter out the null values and i'm golden!! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select firstname, sum(malecount) males, sum(femalecount) females
from 
(select 'boys' gender
,firstname
, 0 femalecount
, count(*)  malecount
from babynames
where sex = 'male'
group by 'boys, firstname, 0
union
similar query for girls
) temp
group by firstname
```

Comment: I didn't reject the suggested edit but your edit is incorrect. `SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` is not the sam with `SUM(COUNT)` http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1546281